# Best and worst case - Time compexity

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

I have to find the Best and worst case of an algorithm, but I don't understand the results:

```
int chOne=1; 
for (int i=0; i<list.lenght; i++) 
    if(list[i]<list[chOne]){ 
       chOne=i;
    } 
return chOne;
```

BC:2c+2c(n-1)=2cn
WC:2c+3c(n-1)=3cn-c

I don't know what is the "n-1"; and following other similar exercises, it would be (I think)

BC:5c
WC:3c+2cn

Could someone tell me why is not like this?
Thank you!

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Why the best case is 2cn and not 5c?

Comment: I can't tell without more information on the problem. The stuff inside the `for` and `if` is probably importan.

Comment: thank you, i've edited and maybe now it's clearer to understand

Comment: n is the length of your list. The reason why your best case can't possibly be 5c is that you always go through the entire list, and 5c doesn't mention n at all.

Comment: oh! ok, I think I understand better now, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precise numbers depend on what you consider atomic operations in the algorithmic model.

However, it always holds that

- the entire list is visited, with incrementing the current index `i`,  testing for loop termination and checking for a new minimum in each iteration.
- whenever the currently visited element of the list is smaller than the current minimum candidate indexed by `chOne`, an update operation takes place.

So your best case is, when no update ever occurs ( that is the case if the initial choice of `chOne` indexes the smallest list element ) and in the worst case an update takes place on every iteration but 1, the latter being the iteration when the current list index equals the original choice of `chOne` (Either there has already been an update, then the currently indexed element cannot be smaller than the current choice, or the original index chocie has been `0`, then both indexes are the same).

With `n` Representing the list length, `2c` Being the fixed cost of each iteration and `c` the cost of a `chOne` update, you have 1 iteration guaranteed to cost `2c` and `n-1` iterations each with cost at least `2c` And possibly `3c`.